# Send information with ajax and go to another page

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have one.php where I load two.php with jQuery/Ajax. I want to do something in two.php and then make one.php go to three.php

(With the code I have here, the loaded page goes to three but not the whole HTML page one.php)

one.php: (HTML document)

```
$(function(){
     $("#send").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").text();    
        $("#loaded").load("two.php",
        { name: name },
        function(){
            //I cannot send to three.php here as I need some information that is processed in two.php
        }); 
     });
}

<div id="name" contenteditable="true">Name</div>
<div id="send">Send</div>
<br>
<div id="loaded"></div>
```

two.php: (only PHP)

```
if( isset($_POST["name"]) ){    
    // do something an then send one.php to three.php
    header('Location: three.php');
}
```

Comment: $("#loaded").load("two.php",
        function(response, status, xhr ){
    if(status == "success")
     document.location.href = 'path_here';
    
  });

Comment: do you have any script in two.php ?

Comment: @Asma Mech. If I understand, what you do is the same that I already have provided. See my comment "I cannot send to three.php here as I need some information that is processed in two.php"

Comment: @iraajan. I already have provided what it is in two.php, see my question. Perhaps I do not understand your answer?